# Quiero que el usuario aparezca solo una vez en los resultados de búsqueda

Tags: php

He desarrollado un buscador en mi sitio donde se puede buscar un usuario del sitio web y un producto.
Pero resulta que el usuario aparece mas de una vez en la búsqueda y yo no quiero que eso sea así.

No se si me he dado a entender bien, quiero cuando una persona realice una búsqueda en mi sitio web de un usuario por ejemplo, solo quiero que no me vuelva a mostrar el usuario que ya me ha mostrado en la parte de arriba o parte superior, en lo demás el sitio esta trabajando de manera correcta.

Quiero que el usuario aparezca solo una vez en la buscada, solo si coinciden los resultados
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Acá esta el código backend de la pagina search:**

```
<?php

require_once('./conexion/conexion.php');
require_once('./functions/functions.php');

// Obtener la ip del visitante
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// Obtener el navegador del visitante
$browser = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

$browser = getBrowserName($browser);

$errors = '';

if(isset($_GET['search'])){
    $search = $_GET['search'];

    // validar que no nos intruduscan codigo
    $search = htmlspecialchars($search);
    $search = trim($search);
    $search = filter_var($search, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    // Si search llega vacio, redirigeme a la home
    if(empty($search)){
        header('Location: /bomgos');
    }

    // Restringir cantidad de carateres
    $searchLen = strlen($search);
    if($searchLen >= 245){
        $errors = "El limite de careteres es de 245 y has colocado $searchLen <br/><br/>";
    }

    // Si la busqueda es menor o igual a 245, me va a guardar la busqueda en la base de datos
    if($searchLen <= 245){
        $statement = $conexion->prepare('INSERT INTO search (id_search, search, ip, browser, create_at_search) VALUES(
            null, :search, :ip, :browser, NOW())'
        );
        $statement->execute(array(
            ':search' => $search,
            ':ip' => $ip,
            ':browser' => $browser
        ));
    }


    // sacar todo lo que coicida con la busqueda
    $stetament = $conexion->prepare(
        "SELECT *, users.id_usuario, users.name, users.surname, users.photo_perfil, users.description_user, .users.create_at_user FROM product INNER JOIN users ON users.id_usuario = product.user_id WHERE users.name LIKE :search OR users.surname LIKE :search OR title LIKE :search OR description_product LIKE :search OR ubication LIKE :search OR price LIKE :search OR category LIKE :search OR condicion LIKE :search LIMIT 40"
    );
    $stetament->execute(array(':search' => "%$search%"));
    $result = $stetament->fetchAll();

    if(empty($result)){
        $errors .= "No se ha encontrado resultado para: <strong>$search</strong>";
    }
} else {
    header('Location: /bomgos');
}


?>
```

**Código frontend, html:**

```
<?php

require_once('conexion/conexion.php');
require_once('backend/search.php');
require_once('functions/functions.php');
// require_once('pagination/pagination.search.php');


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Resultados de tu busqueda: <?=$search?> | Bomgos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize-icons.css">
    <meta name="description" content="<?=$search?>" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?=$search?>, Resultados, Buscar" />
    <meta name="author" content="Dailin Ivan Payano" />
    <meta name="owner" content="Dailin Ivan Payano" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon/favicon.svg" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <?php require_once('frontend/header.php') ?>

    <!-- Main -->
    <main class="container">
        <h1 class="flow-text">Resultado de busqueda: <strong class="blue-text"><?php echo $search ?></strong></h1>
        <div class="divider"></div>

        <?php if(isset($errors)) : ?>
            <h2><?=$errors?></h2>
        <?php endif ?>

        <section class="section">
            <article class="row">
                <div class="col s10">

                <?php foreach($result as $post) : ?>
                    <!-- Enlace al perfil -->
                    <a href="profile?id=<?=$post['id_usuario']?>&user=<?=$post['name'].' '.$post['surname']?>">
                                
                        <p class="col s12">
                            <!-- Foto de perfil -->
                            <div class="col s3">
                                <img src="photo-perfil/<?=$post['photo_perfil']?>" alt="<?=$post['name'].' '.$post['surname']?>" class="circle" height="100">
                            </div>

                            <!-- Nombre -->
                            <strong class="black-text"><?=$post['name'].' '.$post['surname']?></strong><br>

                            <!-- Fecha -->
                            <i class="black-text"><?=form_fecha($post['create_at_user'])?></i><br>

                            <!-- Descripcion -->
                            <p class="grey-text"><?=substr($post['description_user'], 0, 200).'...'?></p><br><br>
                            <div class="col s12 divider"></div>
                        </p>

                    </a><!-- End enlace al perfil -->
                <?php endforeach ?>

                </div>
            </article>
        </section>

            <section class="section">
                <article class="row">

                    <div class="col s10">
                        <?php foreach($result as $post) : ?>

                        <?php
                        // Pasar esta variable por la URL
                        $titleURL = str_replace(' ', '-', $post['title']);
                        $titleURL = strtolower($titleURL);    
                            
                        ?>

                        <!-- Si es igual a null, muestramelo -->
                        <?php if($post['state'] == null) : ?>

                            <a href="detail?id=<?php echo $post['id_producto'] ?>&title=<?=$titleURL?>">
                            
                                <!-- Imagen del producto -->
                                <p>
                                    <img src="miniaturas/<?php echo $post['miniatura'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $post['title'] ?>" title="<?php echo $post['title'] ?>" class="responsive-img col s12 m6 xl5" height="170">
                                </p>

                                <!-- Titulo del producto -->
                                <h1 class="flow-text black-text" title="<?php echo $post['title'] ?>">
                                    <?php echo substr($post['title'], 0, 60).'...' ?>
                                </h1>

                                <!-- Precio del producto -->
                                <strong class="green-text"><?=$post['moneda'].' '.$post['price']?></strong> <span class="grey-text">&#8226;</span> 
                                <span class="grey-text">de</span>

                                 <!-- Nombre -->
                                <a href="profile?id=<?=$post['id_usuario']?>">
                                    <strong class="grey-text"><?=$post['name'].' '.$post['surname']?></strong>
                                </a>

                                <!-- Descripcion del producto -->
                                <p class="grey-text">
                                    <?php echo substr($post['description_product'], 0, 80).'...' ?>
                                </p><br/><br>

                            </a>
                            <?php $post_id = $post['id_producto'] ?>

                        <?php endif ?>

                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </div>

                </article>
            </section>
    </main>

    <!-- Menu pc -->
    <?php require_once('menu/menu.pc.php') ?>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <?php require_once('frontend/footer.php') ?>

    <script src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Un cordial saludo

Comment: Saludos. Hace falta pongas el código que corresponde al HTML donde formas lo que muestras; debes considerar, que tu `select` tiene `product` y `users` (supongo) que si un usuario tiene mas de 1 producto por tanto (y es la razón) sale mas de 1 registro; tal que, la situación no se presenta mal, sino es el proceso mediante el cual procesas los datos lo que debes corregir a fin que c/vez que es el mismo user no dibujar de nuevo esa parte sino hasta que cambie.

Comment: @RobertoLeOr Disculpa por no ver colocado el código de html, tal parece que olvide ponerlo, creí verlo puesto. Gracias por interesarte en mi pregunta

Comment: @xelfury si le quito la `,` no me saca ningun resultado y lo mismo pasa si le quito el `*`

Comment: @xelfury pero si puedes por favor, dame el código de la sentencia como tu lo sugieres para de esa forma ver si logro resolver mi problema

Comment: Esta es la estructura de mi base de datos `SELECT *, users.id_usuario, users.name, users.surname, users.photo_perfil, users.description_user, .users.create_at_user FROM product INNER JOIN users ON users.id_usuario = product.user_id WHERE users.name LIKE :search OR users.surname LIKE :search OR title LIKE :search OR description_product LIKE :search OR ubication LIKE :search OR price LIKE :search OR category LIKE :search OR condicion LIKE :search LIMIT 40"`

Comment: @xelfury Ya logre resolverlo, pero tuve que hacer otro consulta adicionar en la parte del html, ahora mismo muestro el código

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigos, ya logre resolver mi pregunta, solo tuve que hacer una consulta adicional en la parte del *frontend*, se que no es buena practica mesclar el *html* con la lógica, pero de esta manera logre resolver mi problema. en vez de hacer un *foreach* lo que hice fue un *while* de usuarios para que me muestre los resultados de la búsqueda de usuario separado de la búsqueda de producto, de esta manera simplemente estoy haciendo 2 buscada a la vez, una de usuario y una de producto mostrando ambos resultados pero todo en una misma búsqueda

**Código frontend, HTML ya resuelto:**

```
<?php

require_once('conexion/conexion.php');
require_once('backend/search.php');
require_once('functions/functions.php');

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Resultados de tu busqueda: <?=$search?> | Bomgos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="materialize/css/materialize-icons.css">
    <meta name="description" content="<?=$search?>" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="<?=$search?>, Resultados, Buscar" />
    <meta name="author" content="Dailin Ivan Payano" />
    <meta name="owner" content="Dailin Ivan Payano" />
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon/favicon.svg" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Header -->
    <?php require_once('frontend/header.php') ?>

    <!-- Main -->
    <main class="container">
        <h1 class="flow-text">Resultado de busqueda: <strong class="blue-text"><?php echo $search ?></strong></h1>
        <div class="divider"></div>

        <?php if(isset($errors)) : ?>
            <h2><?=$errors?></h2>
        <?php endif ?>

        <section>
            <article class="row">
                <div class="col s10">

                <?php 
                
                // Sacar el nombre de la persona que ha iniciado sesion
                $stmt = $conexion->query("SELECT id_usuario, name, surname, photo_perfil, description_user, create_at_user FROM users WHERE name LIKE '%$search%' OR surname LIKE '%$search%'");
                $stmt->execute(['email' => $email]);
                while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

                    // Los datos del usuario
                    $id_user = $row['id_usuario'];
                    $name = $row['name'];
                    $surname = $row['surname'];
                    $foto = $row['photo_perfil'];
                    $description = $row['description_user'];
                    $fecha = $row['create_at_user'];

                
                ?>
                    <!-- Enlace al perfil -->
                    <a href="profile?id=<?=$id_user?>&user=<?=$name.$surname?>">
                                
                        <p class="col s12">
                            <!-- Foto de perfil -->
                            <div class="col s3">
                                <img src="photo-perfil/<?=$foto?>" alt="<?=$name.' '.$surname?>" class="circle" height="100">
                            </div>

                            <!-- Nombre -->
                            <strong class="black-text"><?=$name.' '.$surname?></strong><br>

                            <!-- Fecha -->
                            <i class="black-text"><?=form_fecha($fecha)?></i><br>

                            <!-- Descripcion -->
                            <p class="grey-text"><?=substr($description, 0, 200).'...'?></p><br><br>
                            <div class="col s12 divider"></div>
                        </p>

                    </a><!-- End enlace al perfil -->
                <?php } ?>

                </div>
            </article>
        </section>

            <section class="section">
                <article class="row">

                    <div class="col s10">
                        <?php foreach($result as $post) : ?>

                        <?php
                        // Pasar esta variable por la URL
                        $titleURL = str_replace(' ', '-', $post['title']);
                        $titleURL = strtolower($titleURL);    
                            
                        ?>

                        <!-- Si es igual a null, muestramelo -->
                        <?php if($post['state'] == null) : ?>

                            <a href="detail?id=<?php echo $post['id_producto'] ?>&title=<?=$titleURL?>">
                            
                                <!-- Imagen del producto -->
                                <p>
                                    <img src="miniaturas/<?php echo $post['miniatura'] ?>" alt="<?php echo $post['title'] ?>" title="<?php echo $post['title'] ?>" class="responsive-img col s12 m6 xl5" height="170">
                                </p>

                                <!-- Titulo del producto -->
                                <h1 class="flow-text black-text" title="<?php echo $post['title'] ?>">
                                    <?php echo substr($post['title'], 0, 60).'...' ?>
                                </h1>

                                <!-- Precio del producto -->
                                <strong class="green-text"><?=$post['moneda'].' '.$post['price']?></strong> <span class="grey-text">&#8226;</span> 
                                <span class="grey-text">de</span>

                                 <!-- Nombre -->
                                <a href="profile?id=<?=$post['id_usuario']?>">
                                    <strong class="grey-text"><?=$post['name'].' '.$post['surname']?></strong>
                                </a>

                                <!-- Descripcion del producto -->
                                <p class="grey-text">
                                    <?php echo substr($post['description_product'], 0, 80).'...' ?>
                                </p><br/><br>

                            </a>
                            <?php $post_id = $post['id_producto'] ?>

                        <?php endif ?>

                        <?php endforeach ?>
                    </div>

                </article>
            </section>
    </main>

    <!-- Menu pc -->
    <?php require_once('menu/menu.pc.php') ?>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <?php require_once('frontend/footer.php') ?>

    <script src="materialize/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```